# Summing values of Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to sum all the values in a dictionary in Java (helping my kid with homework, I never work in Java). Here's what I've tried:

```
    Hashtable<Int, Int> jim_dict = new Hashtable<Int, Int>();
    Hashtable<Int, Int> pam_dict = new Hashtable<Int, Int>();

    int totalJimVotes() {
        int sum = 0;

        (int value: jim_dict.values()) {
            sum += value;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    int totalPamVotes() {
        int sum = 0;

        (int value : pam_dict.values()) {
            sum += value;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

What did I foul up syntax-wise? I found another answer on SO for summing float values, but the syntax for it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `Int` is not a valid Java type - try `Integer` instead

Comment: Please use Integer

Comment: also you should precede the loop block with the `for` keyword, e.g. `for(int value : dict.values())...`

Comment: HashTable is work with Wrapper class not primitive data type.

Comment: `return jim_dict.keySet().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();` should work, right?

Comment: Additionally, you should not use `Hashtable` in modern code; use `Map` (specifically `HashMap`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Example of Sums.

Use jim_dict.values() for sum of values.

Use jim_dict.keySet() for sum of keys.

```
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> jim_dict = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
        jim_dict.put(1, 10);
        jim_dict.put(2, 20);
        System.out.println("Values Sum:" + jim_dict.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
        System.out.println("Keys Sum:" + jim_dict.keySet().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
```